# Why are nitrogenous bases of DNA hydrophobic if they can hydrogen bond?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry, dna

Why are nitrogenous bases of DNA hydrophobic if they can hydrogen bond?

Is it that they are only relatively hydrophobic?

[This forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/2-questions.222122/) explains it but does not give an example of the structure.

Comment: This is better off at Chemistry.SE and I voted to close.

Comment: They are not hydrophobic.. They are quite water soluble. See [this data sheet](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma/Product_Information_Sheet/a8626pis.pdf) for adenine.

Comment: @AliceD This is about biological molecules, I see no reason why it would be off-topic here.

Comment: @MadScientist But this is about solubility, so these are physical properties of the molecule. This fits better into chemistry or physics.

Comment: @MadScientist - I don't see any clue to any biological compound in the Q. I know, implicitly I can autocomplete this question with amino acids etc etc, but I don't see it in the Q. Until placed in a Bio framework, I leave my close-vote where it is :) Plus, the link to a physics forum speaks for itself.

Comment: Definitely more of a chemistry question. Short version: In addition to hydrogen bonds between pairs of bases, interactions between stacked aromatic purine and pyrimidine rings of nucleotides stabilize DNA molecules.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stacking_(chemistry)

Comment: @AliceD Nitrogenous base generally refers to the nucleobases in RNA and DNA, and those are certainly biological molecules. The question about hydrophobicity and hydrogen bonding also have biological implications.

Comment: @AliceD The question was asked in the biology section of physicsforums.com ;) I think this is on-topic here. Plus there are plenty of question on DNA and more that chemistry SE doesn't send our way.

Comment: The term "nitrogenous bases" was confusing; so I fixed it. This is a question on biochemistry and most biochemists would know the answer. I would not consider this off-topic. Note that questions should be pushed to chemistry SE only if they concern certain advanced concepts that are not generally covered in basic biochemistry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two concepts are not mutually exclusive. You have constructed a false dichotomy.  Both of these facts are true:

1. The electrons in the pi orbitals of the conjugated double bonds in the planar rings are hydrophobic and can "stack" on each other as shown in this drawing of a DNA helix where the bases are shown as planar rectangles:

[image: A model of a kinked DNA helix]

2. The nitrogen and oxygen molecules (either in the rings, or as substituents on the rings) can participate in hydrogen bonds (H-bonds):

[image: H-bonds in Watson Crick base pairs]

There are other examples of hydrophobicity and H-bonds co-existing.  For example on the interior of proteins.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand the answer. Why are both the facts true? I think that is what I want to understand more.

Comment: Hydrophobicity and and hydrophilicity aren't yes/no things, they're gradients.

Comment: @Whitecat Most detergents are also hydrophobic and hydrophilic at the same time.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that no, the DNA bases aren't in themselves completely hydrophobic, but in the region of the planar face of each base is a zone of hydrophobicity. In this way, base stacking becomes favorable where water molecules would otherwise attempt to order themselves to maximize hydrogen bonding with each other.

Comment: @Kendall Can you add that to the the answer?